# AWS lightsail phpmyadmin inaccessible

Tags: phpmyadmin, amazon-lightsail

I just set up my AWS lightsail and as a first step decided to try the phpmyadmin using bitnami.

I am able to follow the process of setting up the SSH connection **successfully**

but when I try to go to url

```
http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin
```

It automatically goes to my my domain `https://www.mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin` with error:

```
For security reasons, this URL is only accessible using localhost (127.0.0.1) as the hostname.
```

I am unable to land to any relevant results from google search.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a late answer, but even I faced this problem and solved it as below.

**The problem is in your server you have enabled force HTTPS redirect (maybe while setting up SSL certificate)**

The solution to access PHPMyAdmin using HTTPS is as below:

1. Make an SSH tunnel:

   ```
   ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:443 -i EXMAPLE.pem USER_NAME@IP_ADDRESS
   ```
2. Now access PHPMyAdmin using https://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/

Hope it will solve your problem.